# Pandas DataFrame - Duplicate Columns and Update rows at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas  data frame as shown below. I would like to duplicate Column A with a new Column B, and at the same time add an incremental number starting with 001 for all rows starting with LineName-01, and then do the same for all rows starting with BlockName-01.

Input DataFrame:

```
      Column A
1   LineName-1
2   LineName-2
3   LineName-3
4   BlockName-1
5   BlockName-2
6   BlockName-3
```

Desired Output DataFrame:

```
      Column A  Column B
1   LineName-1  LineName-1_001
2   LineName-2  LineName-2_002
3   LineName-3  LineName-3_003
4   BlockName-1 BlockName-1_001
5   BlockName-2 BlockName-2_002
6   BlockName-3 BlockName-3_003
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df['Column B'] = df["Column A"] + (
    df.groupby(df["Column A"].str.split("-").str[0]).cumcount() + 1
).apply("_{:03}".format)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      Column A         Column B
1   LineName-1   LineName-1_001
2   LineName-2   LineName-2_002
3   LineName-3   LineName-3_003
4  BlockName-1  BlockName-1_001
5  BlockName-2  BlockName-2_002
6  BlockName-3  BlockName-3_003
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['Column B'] = (df['Column A']+'_'
                  +df.groupby(df['Column A'].str.extract(r'^([^-]+)',
                                                         expand=False))
                     .cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(3)
                  )

      Column A         Column B
0   LineName-1   LineName-1_001
1   LineName-2   LineName-2_002
2   LineName-3   LineName-3_003
3  BlockName-1  BlockName-1_001
4  BlockName-2  BlockName-2_002
5  BlockName-3  BlockName-3_003
```